# Extract the content from set of xml files using php

Tags: php, xml

I have set of xml files in the same structure. What I want to do is extract the content from set of files or from the specified folder.
The structure look like in all the xml files,

```
...
<FAQs>
<content> test</content>
<creator>myname</creator>
</FAQs>
...
```

How this can be achieved using php?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a google question....

Answer (score 2):

- Get all the files, e.g. with [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)
- iterate over the files with a loop
- load the files with [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)
- Now you've got objects of the XMLs